# How can I extract multiple column from cell in excel using R?

Tags: r, json, excel

My data is from Json and it's csv file now. 
In one cell, it looks like this.

`{"A":1048512,"B":1048512,"C":1048512,"D":1048512,"E":1048512,"F":0,"G":0}`

I'd like to extract the words within the quote into colume name, for example, "A"-> column name A, and fill the cell under the column name "A" with the number next to ":"

There are IDs of each row and more columns to be sorted like this. 
Some cells have more than 20 different data which need to be changed into column. 
What kind of code can I use for this in R?
I don't have the original Json file.

Excel file from Json
cell includes multiple column data, like this:

`{"A":1048512,"B":1048512,"C":1048512,"D":1048512,"E":1048512,"F":0,"G":0}`

Comment: What have you tried and where have you run into problems.  In Excel, you would use a JSON parser in VBA.  Isn't there one in `R` also?

Answer (score 1):

I'll generate a "full" sample dataset, please provide your own if this doesn't adequately demonstrate things. (For the record, in true comma-delimited files, a double-quote is escaped with two double-quotes.)

```r
dat <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
id,json
1,"{""A"":1048512,""B"":1048512,""C"":1048512,""D"":1048512,""E"":1048512,""F"":0,""G"":0}"
2,"{""A"":1048512,""B"":1048512,""C"":1048512,""D"":1048512,""E"":1048512,""F"":0,""G"":0}"')
```

From here, it's just parsing a column of json data and bringing it back in:

```r
tmp <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(dat$json, jsonlite::fromJSON))
str(tmp)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  7 variables:
#  $ A: int  1048512 1048512
#  $ B: int  1048512 1048512
#  $ C: int  1048512 1048512
#  $ D: int  1048512 1048512
#  $ E: int  1048512 1048512
#  $ F: int  0 0
#  $ G: int  0 0
cbind(dat[, "json" != names(dat), drop = FALSE], tmp)
#    id       A       B       C       D       E F G
# 2   1 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 0 0
# 21  2 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 0 0
```

---

A problem can arise if not every element is proper json. For example:

```r
dat <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
id,json
1,"{""A"":1048512,""B"":1048512,""C"":1048512,""D"":1048512,""E"":1048512,""F"":0,""G"":0}"
2,"{""A"":1048512,""B"":1048512,""C"":1048512,""D"":1048512,""E"":1048512,""F"":0,""G"":0}"
3,')

tmp <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(dat$json, jsonlite::fromJSON))
# Error: parse error: premature EOF
#                                        
#                      (right here) ------^
```

To remedy this, let's just guard against it:

```r
tmp <- lapply(dat$json, function(a) tryCatch(jsonlite::fromJSON(a),
                                             error = function(e) NULL))
# create an "empty" (NA) similarly-structured frame for replacement
empty <- Filter(Negate(is.null), tmp)[[1]]
empty[] <- lapply(empty, function(ign) NA)
# replace all NULL with this new empty
tmp <- lapply(tmp, function(a) if (is.null(a)) empty else a)
str(tmp)
# List of 3
#  $ :List of 7
#   ..$ A: int 1048512
#   ..$ B: int 1048512
#   ..$ C: int 1048512
#   ..$ D: int 1048512
#   ..$ E: int 1048512
#   ..$ F: int 0
#   ..$ G: int 0
#  $ :List of 7
#   ..$ A: int 1048512
#   ..$ B: int 1048512
#   ..$ C: int 1048512
#   ..$ D: int 1048512
#   ..$ E: int 1048512
#   ..$ F: int 0
#   ..$ G: int 0
#  $ :List of 7
#   ..$ A: logi NA
#   ..$ B: logi NA
#   ..$ C: logi NA
#   ..$ D: logi NA
#   ..$ E: logi NA
#   ..$ F: logi NA
#   ..$ G: logi NA
cbind(dat[, "json" != names(dat), drop = FALSE],
      do.call(rbind.data.frame, tmp))
#    id       A       B       C       D       E  F  G
# 2   1 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512  0  0
# 21  2 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512  0  0
# 3   3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA NA\
```

---

Another problem: if the fields (names and count) are not the same in all of the 'json' fields, then normal R will need a bit extra work to make it work.

```r
dat <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
id,json
1,"{""A"":1048512,""B"":1048512,""C"":1048512,""D"":1048512,""E"":1048512,""F"":0,""G"":0}"
2,"{""AAA"":1048512,""B"":1048512,""C"":1048512,""D"":1048512,""E"":1048512,""F"":0,""G"":0}"')
tmp <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(dat$json, jsonlite::fromJSON))
# Error in match.names(clabs, nmi) : names do not match previous names
```

For simplicity here, I'll use one of `dplyr` or `data.table` for the `rbind`ing part, as their defaults are a little more accommodating:

```r
tmp <- lapply(dat$json, jsonlite::fromJSON)
dplyr::bind_rows(tmp)
# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#         A       B       C       D       E     F     G     AAA
#     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <int>   <int>
# 1 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512     0     0      NA
# 2      NA 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512     0     0 1048512
data.table::rbindlist(tmp, fill = TRUE)
# similar output
tmp <- dplyr::bind_rows(tmp) # either one works
cbind(dat[, "json" != names(dat), drop = FALSE], tmp)
#   id       A       B       C       D       E F G     AAA
# 1  1 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 0 0      NA
# 2  2      NA 1048512 1048512 1048512 1048512 0 0 1048512
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Your codes worked with half of the data but some of them are double framed by themselves. For example, in one cell, {"colour":{"black":[1525,1648,122876],"group":[1]},"number":{"media":null,"mediaGroup":null}} like this. I'd like to seperate them into isolated column, such as column name : 'colour_black', 'colour_group', 'number' like this. Is it possible to extraxt the colname from these cells? I tried to modify your code, but it didn't work well.

Comment: And in another data, there is a problem because in one column, some cells have  {"region":{"T":["99","09"],"OTHERS":[]}} this kind of value
, and others look like this {"except":{"TT":[],"OTHERS":["00"]}}. Because they have 2 different outer frame, 'region' and 'except', I think code above does not work well. Thanks again.

Comment: (1) Your question data looks nothing like that, so I don't know what to say there. (2) Sample data ... I can't guess what to do without proper sample data. If you add 1-2 of each "type" of line in your file, I might be able to help.